# In Google Analytics > User explorer, Clientid shows a "loaded" line... what is it?

Tags: google-analytics, users, reporting

When looking into **GA > Audience > User explorer**... I have a line displaying "**loaded**" instead of an usual clientid :

[image: e-ana**strong text**]

What does that mean ?

Is there some issue with my tracking to get the correct clientid?

Comment: It's either a misconfiguration of your tracker, or a spam injection. Most non-expert GA users wouldn't ever touch client-id, so I'd guess some spammer is hitting your GA tracking url and injecting some dummy data. Is it a lot of traffic?

Comment: Thanks for the insights... aprently not a spam but a loop created by a script that was checking the client-id for cross-domain tracking... This was the result + page views dulpicate.